# What does from json import loads mean?

Tags: python

Please ignore the following paragraph. Hello ladies and gentlemen. What a great day to be on the internet surfing the WWW. I've had the pleasure to induce myself with highly concentrated caffeine drinks that are keeping me up all night. I really don't understand Python because I never actually learned it or any other programming language for that matter. I've been forced to code lately. I'm not much of a code I just rip someone else's code and put my name on it. This is how I roll, and if you don't like it, you can thumb this down and move on. IDC which stands for I don't care.

```
from json import loads
j=loads(txt)
j=loads(m.groups()[0])
print(j)
```

Comment: Who is forcing you to code?

Answer (score 0):

It means, to import `loads` variable from `json` module.

Comment: what's a variable?

Comment: actually it is a function

Comment: i know, but how do i use these loads?

Comment: @BookmarkScraper Variables are nothing but reserved memory locations to store values.

Comment: @AntonvBR And a function is also a value, at least in Python.

Comment: @K._ Nope I wouldn't say so. A function is also a class (but that's just stretching it), but it is can be stored in a variable

Comment: okay. what's the difference between 
    j=loads(txt)
    j=loads(m.groups()[0])

Comment: @BookmarkScraper Both of them use the loads function from the json library and assign the return value to the j variable. But it is strange as the 2nd line overwrites the first.

Comment: m=search(r'<code id="currentjob"><!--(.*?)--></code>', text)
        if m:
            txt=m.groups()[0]
            j=loads(txt)


**what does that function mean?
i know they overwrite each other. I'm pasting the entire code because it's too long.**

Comment: @BookmarkScraper Well you are dealing with an XML-string using the RE library to search for patterns.

Comment: @BookmarkScraper Give some tutorial a chance and try to learn the very basics of Python. Almost everyone here started sometime copy-pasting code and then went on to read docs to understand more. Why you would be forced to code, I don't know but if you really need to Python is a good first language I'd say. Try reading about the followin libraries: os, json, pandas, requests, re .... I use them every day.

Comment: i heard lxml was heard. ughhh. thank you so much Andon!!

Comment: I'm being forced to code because I don't want to copy and paste 500 items into an excel sheet one-by-one.